# Android java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5 When click on listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Get this error when click listview

> MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index
>   5, size is 5
>                                                                                             at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                                                             at com.integrasys.ekontrak.Main$getIklan$1.onItemClick(Main.java:276)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3872)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3627)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)

Whats wrong with my coding?

protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

```
        String status = null;
        String status_desc = null;

        /*
         * Will make http call here This call will download required data
         * before launching the app
         * example:
         * 1. Downloading and storing SQLite
         * 2. Downloading images
         * 3. Parsing the xml / json
         * 4. Sending device information to server
         * 5. etc.,
         */
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        String jsonStrUser = sh.makeServiceCall(getResources().getString(R.string.IKLAN_API), ServiceHandler.GET, null);
        Log.e(TAG_MAIN,"Response: " + jsonStrUser);
        if (jsonStrUser != null) {
            try {



                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStrUser);

                Log.e(TAG_MAIN,"jsonObj: " + jsonObj);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");
                Log.e(TAG_MAIN,"error: " + error);
                if(error){
                    Log.e(TAG_MAIN,"error");
                    status = "0";
                    status_desc = jsonObj.getString("msg");
                }else{

                    iklan = jsonObj.getJSONArray("msg");

                    int len = iklan.length();

                    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {


                        JSONObject msg = iklan.getJSONObject(i);
                        iklanid = msg.getString(TAG_IKLANID);
                        istender = msg.getString(TAG_ISTENDER);
                        tajukiklan = msg.getString(TAG_TAJUKIKLAN);
                        startsale = msg.getString(TAG_STARTSALE);
                        endsale = msg.getString(TAG_ENDSALE);
                        closedate = msg.getString(TAG_CLOSEDATE);


                        switch (istender) {
                            case "0":
                                //Your Code as you specified in your code context.
                                HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap();
                                map1.put(TAG_IKLANID, iklanid);
                                map1.put(TAG_ISTENDER, istender);
                                map1.put(TAG_TAJUKIKLAN, tajukiklan);
                                map1.put(TAG_STARTSALE, startsale);
                                map1.put(TAG_ENDSALE, endsale);
                                map1.put(TAG_CLOSEDATE, closedate);

                                sebuthargaList.add(map1);



                                break;
                            case "1":
                                //Your Code as you specified in your code context.
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
                                map.put(TAG_IKLANID, iklanid);
                                map.put(TAG_ISTENDER, istender);
                                map.put(TAG_TAJUKIKLAN, tajukiklan);
                                map.put(TAG_STARTSALE, startsale);
                                map.put(TAG_ENDSALE, endsale);
                                map.put(TAG_CLOSEDATE, closedate);
                                tenderList.add(map);


                                break;
                        }



                    }

                    status = "1";
                    status_desc = getResources().getString(R.string.login_success);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return status + "~" + status_desc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // After completing http call
        // will close this activity and lauch main activity
        String[] arr_result = TextUtils.split(result, "~");

           pDialog.dismiss();

        if (arr_result[0].equals("1")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arr_result[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, sebuthargaList, R.layout.row_item,
                    new String[]{TAG_TAJUKIKLAN,TAG_STARTSALE,TAG_ENDSALE,TAG_CLOSEDATE},
                    new int[]{R.id.txtsebutharga, R.id.txttarikhmula, R.id.txttarikhtamat, R.id.txttarikhtutup});
            listSebutharga.setAdapter(adapter);


            listSebutharga.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String tajuk  = sebuthargaList.get(position).get(TAG_TAJUKIKLAN);
                    String startsale = sebuthargaList.get(position).get(TAG_STARTSALE);
                    String ensale = sebuthargaList.get(position).get(TAG_ENDSALE);
                    String closedate = sebuthargaList.get(position).get(TAG_CLOSEDATE);

                   Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IklanDetail.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TAJUKIKLAN, tajuk);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_STARTSALE, startsale);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_ENDSALE, ensale);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CLOSEDATE, closedate);

                   startActivity(in);
                    finish();

                }
            });


            ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, tenderList, R.layout.row_item,
                    new String[]{TAG_TAJUKIKLAN,TAG_STARTSALE,TAG_ENDSALE,TAG_CLOSEDATE},
                    new int[]{R.id.txtsebutharga, R.id.txttarikhmula, R.id.txttarikhtamat, R.id.txttarikhtutup});
            listTender.setAdapter(adapter2);

            listTender.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                    String tajuk  = tenderList.get(position).get(TAG_TAJUKIKLAN);
                    String startsale = tenderList.get(position).get(TAG_STARTSALE);
                    String ensale = tenderList.get(position).get(TAG_ENDSALE);
                    String closedate = tenderList.get(position).get(TAG_CLOSEDATE);

                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IklanDetail.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TAJUKIKLAN, tajuk);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_STARTSALE, startsale);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_ENDSALE, ensale);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CLOSEDATE, closedate);

                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();

                }
            });

            Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listSebutharga);
            Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listTender);

           // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arr_result[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: put your adapter here

Comment: the problem is you're trying to access the fifth element of an array/list/... that only has four elements

Comment: @Stultuske actually, by the error he is trying to access the 6th element of an array that have 5

Comment: in doinbackground, if you notice i have 2 array that is sebuthargalist and tenderlist. sebuthargalist have 5 element and tender 1 element. When i click last row of sebuthargalist. it give me the error

Comment: @litelite ya, misspoke there, but the concept remains :)

Comment: please put your complete code here. Where have you declared iklan's length?

Comment: Glad to read that you have solved the problem. But It's better you share it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have used `iklan.length()` before declaring the actual size of it.